# JBoss Deployment Scripts

Tags: jboss, web-deployment

Looking to automate deployment of wars and rars in JBoss 5.1. This should be scriptable and scripts need to be manageable. Could you please recommend any deployment automation products or an approach to script such a thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The expected command line to run this deployment will be:

```
ant -Denv=targetEnvironment jboss-deploy
```

Where targetEnvironment specifies the target deployment environment.

To get started, you need to add an ANT target to verify two things:

```
That an environment has been specified
The corresponding env.properties file exists.
```

For more details visit [here](http://www.brainhemorage.com/?p=149)

Comment: my question was for production environment

Comment: This is environment independent